# Color each point individually in column chart highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart as shown in the fiddle

```
series: [{
                data: [
                    [ 'Actual Wishlist Requests' , 6000], 
                    [ 'Actual Approved Wishlists', 3000], 
                    [ 'Actual Research Completed', 2000], 
                    [ 'Actual Interviews Scheduled', 1000], 
                    [ 'Actual Successful Interviews', 500], 
                    [ 'Actual Contracts Signed', 50]] 
            }, 
                 { 
                     data: [
                     [ 'Target Wishlist Requests' , 9305 ], 
                     [ 'Target Approved Wishlists', 6557], 
                     [ 'Target Research Completed', 5069], 
                     [ 'Target Interviews Scheduled', 2290], 
                     [ 'Target Successful Interviews', 686], 
                     [ 'Target Contracts Signed', 37]]
            }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sq8fq/1/

I want to color each point with an individual color.

How can i do this with the existing chart?

Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify lots of attributes at the point level, including color. Try something like this:

```
series: [{
      data: [
             {y:6000,color:'red'},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G575t/

Comment: Building on this answer:
Better alternative to specifying color (specially if you have multiple charts in a single container), would be:

`series: [{
      data: [
             { y:6000, color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] }, 
....
`

Where you can programatically control the color index.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `colorByPoint` option, depending on the level of control needed:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Sq8fq/2/
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.colorByPoint